# How to get chalice like features in fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi, chalice

I am familiar with chalice microframework.

I decided to use fastapi + aws for my project.
But got into a confusion, chalice provides event handlers like `on_sqs_message()`, `on_s3_event()`.

How can I get similar feature in fastapi? Any work around possible?

I looked on google but could not find anything which satisfies me.